# {"id"=>"#<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x7428828>"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`comment controller`:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:comment))

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

`index.html.haml`:

```
#post
  = @posts.each do |post|
    .post
      %p= link_to post.content, post_path(@posts)
      .date
        %p
        published
        = time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)
```

`show.html.haml`:

```
.show
  %p= @post.content
    .comments
      %h2= @post.comments.count
      = render @post.comments

      %h3= comment to post
      = render 'comment/form'

  = link_to "edit", edit_post_path(@post)
  = link_to "delete", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}
  = link_to "home", root_path
```

Comment: Please clearly define what your question is and change your title to reflect that. Simply posting code isn't sufficient.

Comment: i am trying to add a commenting fucntionality, and when i go to the Post show page i get the error.

Comment: From the guidelines: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include ... a specific problem or error ... in the question itself._

Answer (score 0):

Change `=` to `-` on the second line of your posted index.html.haml view.